# WPF: Using Expressions in Data Binding to evaluate a true/false

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, expression-blend, expression

I am hoping this is an easy one.

In my viewmodel I have an array that can be empty or can have up to 8 entries. I have 8 buttons on the screen and would like to bind the visibility of a button to the presence of an entry in the corresponding array. So for button 2 I will show it if myArray has more than 1 entry. I was hoping I could do something like: -

```
{{Binding {myArray.Length > 1}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}
```

My thinking (flawed obviously!) being that `myArray.Length > 1` would evaluate to true/false and the value converter would take this and turn it into a visibility.

But it's not working :(

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom Converter for this.

The converter would bind to the array.Length and accept an int as a parameter to define how many items need to be in the array for it to return true. It would check if the binding is null, or if it is greater than the parameter, and return the appropriate Visibility value

Comment: He would at a minimum need to bind to the Length of the array, otherwise it would not update properly when items are added/removed.

Comment: @CodeNaked True, I'll update my answer. I'm used to using ObservableCollections for all list-type DataBindings since it automatically notifies the UI when elements change

Comment: Perfect - that looks like it'll do the job!! Thanks Rachel and CodeNaked!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no that's not possible. The easiest thing to do is to add a property on your view-model, something like:

```
public bool HasItems {
    get {
        return myArray.Length > 1;
    }
}
```

Your object would need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) and raise the PropertyChanged event for "HasItems" when myArray is changed. Then you would bind to HasItems, instead of your array.

Alternatively, you may be able to bind to myArray.Length and build a custom [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that converts 0 to false and any positive integer to true.